# Laravel 5.2 not working in PHP 5.6 with Nginx server

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, laravel-5

I am currently migrating my website from Apache to nginx, but my .htaccess file is not working. How can I use .htaccess in my nginx server?

My nginx config file:

```
server {
#listen 8000;
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
#listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name localhost;

location /phpmyadmin {
           root /usr/share/;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
           location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/;
                   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; # or 127.0.0.1:9000
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           }
           location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                   root /usr/share/;
           }
    }
    location /phpMyAdmin {
           rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

# Remove trailing slash to please routing system.
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
    #try_files $uri =404;
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

What I tried:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data *

sudo chown -R root:root *
```

also I tried to change

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

php artisan cache:clear
```

Mostly questions in google i have read, but nothing helps me.

Comment: What is the error? That you are getting

Comment: _How can I use .htaccess in my nginx server?_ .htaccess file don't work in nginx. It's apache specific feature only.

Comment: doesn't seem like you configured your laravel application anywhere in the nginx config? your root is var/www/html - where is your application?

Comment: @FrankProvost My application in var/www/html/myapp only. then how can i change my config

Comment: Downvoted because you didn't mentioned the error. It could be a thousand things.